# Zend Framework Controller with action as steps

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, controller, action, init

I am working on a register controller to create a account. I send the user to a special url:
www.name.com/activate/1/fdafdsafdasfdsa where 1 is a id en fdafdsafsda is a hash. I check these in the public function init. If the id and hash are right the init does a forward to step1: `$this->_forward('step1', null, null, array());`

Step 1 is a form and if this is posted and correct step 1 does a forward to step2. But now the problem is in step 2 there is also a form. But I don't want to change the url so I use forward. But when posting on step2 he send the user back to step1. What is a good solution to fix this problem?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extra parameter in your form to indicate which step is the current. Then, in your "Controller > predispatch", you can "select" the right method.

But for my personnal use, I prefere to change the URL to point the differents steps (and I implement a check to ensure the user follow the sequence of step).